# Is Sol Martra the Reinkernator for Metafalss?

Tags: ar-tonelico

Both the Towers in Sol Ciel and Sol Cluster has at the top the Reinkernator but in Metafalss the tower was initially hidden and when it reappeared it's top was Sol Matra which was always there from the begining.

I am wondering if Sol Matra is the Reinkernator for the Ar Tonelico Tower in Metafallss. if not then where is it?

Answer (score 1):

The Second Tower doesn't have a Rinkernator due to the fact it was never completed and due to being completely dependent on the First Tower. Similarly, there is no need for one because Frelia was never intended to become a Tower Administrator on the same way Shurelia and Tilia were, which is also the same reason why she is the only one among the Origins that doesn't have a Linkage armor.